# HashMap in PowerShell

Tags: rest, powershell, powershell-5.0

I am facing issues while implementing a HashMap in PowerShell. I have created the HasMap from a ReST reponse using

```
$response_connection_hashmap = $response_connection|foreach {
@{  $_.name = $_.id }
}
```

I am successfully verifying the hasmap using

```
$response_connection_hashmap.GetEnumerator()|Sort-Object Name
```

However while searching for a value by key, I am using below

```
$response_connection_hashmap.Item("Key01")
```

Getting below error

```
Exception getting "Item": "Cannot convert argument "index", with value: 
"Key01", for "get_Item" to type "System.Int32": "Cannot convert value 
"Key01" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct 
format."""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are generating an array of hashtables:

```
$response_connection_hashmap.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

Try this instead:

```
$response_connection_hashmap = @{}
$response_connection|foreach { $response_connection_hashmap.add($_.name, $_.id) }
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick help!!